# How to distinguish between events of a facebook user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

Using the following Facebook GraphQL endpoint

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/events
```

I can see which events a person is interested in or going to, but how would I differentiate between those two? For example, I would only want to receive the events a person is interested in, not the events a person is going to.

`rsvp_status` seems to be only for events you were invited to.

Comment: Not sure getting the user’s events will be possible any more in the future in general. The documentation page that existed for the `user/events` edge has disappeared, `user_events` permission is not listed on the permissions page any more, and I can not select it in Graph API Explorer any more either. I guess it might still work for you here because you granted that permission at some earlier point, but I kinda doubt right now whether it makes sense to develop any functionality based on this at this point.

Comment: @CBroe Why would they remove this feature :/... By the way, under "Events Groups Pages" in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/v2/) I can enable user_events for my application.

Comment: Oh, that’s where they’ve hidden it, I looked under “user permissions” …

Comment: And https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/ says right on top, _“Access to Events on Users and Pages is only available to Facebook Marketing Partners.”_ - so that sounds to me, like they are trying to restrict access to this for normal 3rd party apps. It might be that they still allow access to the events that are somehow “related to” / relevant to the user, and that only access to their own created events won’t be possible any more.